# Itext7 C# How do I get page number to add image to PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-core, itext7

I've searched all over, but all of the documentation focuses on Java answers which don't have the same methods in the .NET version. I am trying to insert an image to specific positions on a PDF, but I am unable to insert them properly. I can get accurate X/Y coordinates but when it inserts into the PDF, it inserts all of them onto the first page only.

I'm also finding that the height and width don't come out the same as the fields they're replacing. The variables in my watch window show the correct height and width, but it ends up compressed on the PDF. This wasn't a problem with itextSharp when I used to use that.

```
var widgets = toSet.GetWidgets();   // toSet is the field to get position from

Rectangle position = widgets[0].GetRectangle().ToRectangle();
PdfPage page = widgets[0].GetPage();

if (position == null)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("Error locating field");
}

// set bottom left corner and width/height of field
float width = position.GetWidth();
float height = position.GetHeight();
float llx = position.GetX();
float lly = position.GetY();

// resize signature image, set position of bottom left corner to x and y coordinates
image.ScaleToFit(width, height);
image.SetFixedPosition(llx, lly);// I want to put the page number in this method override

doc.Add(image);
```

The image.SetFixedPosition() method has an override that takes in an integer page number, but I am unable to find the page number from the field programmattically. It also forces me to set a width and I'd like to keep the width proportional to the height which is what I am setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Determining the Page Number

According to your code you already do have a page object, the `PdfPage page`, and are looking for its page number in the document. You can use the `PdfDocument` method

```
public virtual int GetPageNumber(PdfPage page)
```

for that.

#### Setting Only the Target Page Number of an Image

Also you have an image object, `Image image`, and want to only set the page for it. You can use the `Image` method

```
public virtual Image SetPageNumber(int pageNumber)
```

for that.

Comment: I had to carry my PdfDocument into the method using it. I was trying to look for a page number method on the Document object derived from the PdfDocument and was not seeing anything. You've saved the day thanks!

Comment: If you only have the `Document`, you can use its `public virtual PdfDocument GetPdfDocument()` method to retrieve the underlying `PdfDocument`.